# vb.net active directory question - rename user account and mailbox

Tags: .net, vb.net, proxy, active-directory, directoryservices

I'm trying to rename a user programically and can't figure out the mailbox piece(proxyAddresses).  Any help is appreciated...

Working code below...

```
Public Shared Function renameUser(ByVal curUsername As String, ByVal newUsername As String) As Boolean
    Dim emailSuffix As String = "@here.com"
    Dim userPrincipalSuffix As String = "@here.now"

    Dim user As New DirectoryEntry
    Dim oSearcher As DirectorySearcher = Nothing
    Dim oRoot As DirectoryEntry = Nothing
    Dim oResult As SearchResult
    Try
        oRoot = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" & "ldapserver" & _
                  "/" & "OU=OUWithUsersToChange,OU=Site Users,DC=here,DC=now")
        oSearcher = New DirectorySearcher(oRoot)
        oSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree

        oSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=" & curUsername & "))"
        oSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("uid")
        oSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail")
        oSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mailNickname")
        oSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userPrincipalName")
        oSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName")
        oSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("proxyAddresses")
        oSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("textEncodedORAddress")
        oSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("legacyExchangeDN")

        oResult = oSearcher.FindOne
        user = oResult.GetDirectoryEntry

        Dim lNewList As New List(Of String)
        For Each sAddress As String In user.Properties("proxyAddresses")
            lNewList.Add(sAddress.Replace(curUsername, newUsername))
        Next
        Dim sTextEncodedORAddress As String = user.Properties.Item("textEncodedORAddress").Value
        Dim sLegacyExchangeDN As String = user.Properties.Item("legacyExchangeDN").Value

        user.Properties.Item("uid").Value = newUsername
        user.Properties.Item("mail").Value = newUsername & emailSuffix
        user.Properties.Item("mailNickname").Value = newUsername
        user.Properties.Item("userPrincipalName").Value = newUsername & userPrincipalSuffix
        user.Properties.Item("sAMAccountName").Value = newUsername
        user.Properties("proxyAddresses").Value = lNewList.ToArray
        user.Properties.Item("textEncodedORAddress").Value = sTextEncodedORAddress.Replace(curUsername, newUsername)
        user.Properties.Item("legacyExchangeDN").Value = sLegacyExchangeDN.Replace(curUsername, newUsername)

        user.CommitChanges()
        user.Rename("CN=" & newUsername)

        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    Finally
        user.Dispose()
        oRoot.Dispose()
        oSearcher.Dispose()
        oResult = Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, proxyAddresses is actually an array, not a single value. It is also prefixed with information about the kind of address it is...

**Warning: Ugly code ahead!**

This is some code that I had used before so change the primary e-mail address for user accounts and keep previous addresses (as in switching primary domain names). This might help you make your changes

```
Dim lNewList As New List(Of String)
sPrimaryAddress = sPrimaryAddress.Split("@")(0) & "@" & "example.com"
lNewList.Add("SMTP:" & sPrimaryAddress)
For Each sAddr As String In lPrevList
    lNewList.Add(sAddr) 'which will be a list of values like "smtp:someone@domain.com"'
Next

Dim oUser As DirectoryEntry = oResult.GetDirectoryEntry()
oUser.Properties("mail").Value = sPrimaryAddress
oUser.Properties("ProxyAddresses").Value = lNewList.ToArray()
oUser.CommitChanges()
```

*lPrevList* was a list of the e-mail addresses the user already had attached to their profile. Their primary address starts with **SMTP:** while the others start with **smtp:** (lowercase). You might run unto other values like *x400*, etc..

**Make sure you treat each value with care. You do not want to write a script and then run it across your domain and blow up all the accounts**

Comment: Correct in that it is an array, I have thought about using the add method but was hoping I was missing a simple rename method (like when renaming cn).  I'll test out the following adding in the code to delete the old smtp/x400 addresses and post back if it works.  Thanks.

...While browsing the user LDAP parameters with adsiedit I noticed two others that should be changed (don't have info on hand, will repost).  Would love a simple rename method, if nothing is native to .Net I'll repost what I come up with.

Comment: Your code worked great, final code is above.  I had to also change legacyExchangeDN and textEncodedORAddress.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the .Net Framework 3.5 or better, you're probably better off using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement. That makes it a matter of getting the correct UserPrinciple, altering the Name property, and calling the Save method. It might look something like this:

```
Dim pc As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "COMPANY")
Dim up As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, curUsername)
up.Name = newUsername
up.Save
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a shot.  If it does what the above is doing with System.DirectoryServices then I think this will be great.  I ran into some problems with DS.AccountManagement where it only enumerated enabled users and I couldn't figure out how to limit queries between current OU and sub OUs so I stayed away from it on this task.  Thanks again.

Comment: Sure. Hope it works out. I haven't had the same need so I can only vouch that it *should* according to the documentation.